# AngularJS : How to add a new object into array while using factory and directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-factory

Trying to simulate a *hotel cart*.
Newbie here

**Questions**
**1.** How to add an item to `orders` when clicked on corresponding `Add` button
**2.** Is it correct to use a factory for serving both `menuitems` for `menu` directive and `orderItems` for `cart` directive
**3.** On click of `add` button, where should the *to be called `add`* function be written, in the `factory` or in the `directive`'s controller 
**4.** Is there any way to better this code and its logic?

For those who wish to see the plunkr demo can view the same [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xkP3FGruKSdI9SIDEqvz?p=preview)

**HTML snippet**

```
    <menu></menu>
```

**JS snippet**

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.factory('menuItems',function(){

    return {
        list:function(){
            var items = [{'name':'kabab'},
                 {'name':'chicken'},
                 {'name':'egg'},
                 {'name':'noodles'}];
            return items
        }
    };
})
.factory('cartItems',function(){
    var orders = [];
    return orders;
})
.directive('menu',function(){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        template:"<ul><li ng-repeat='item in menuItems'>"+
                  '{{item.name}}' +
                   "</li></ul>",
        scope:{},
        controllerAs:'menuCtrl',
        controller:function($scope, menuItems){
            console.log("I am in menuDirective and outputting menuItems")
            console.log(menuItems);
            $scope.menuItems = menuItems.list();
        },
        link:function(){

        }
    }
})
.directive('cart',function(){
    return{
    restrict:'E',
    template:"<ul><li ng-repeat='order in cartItems'>"+
                 '{{order.name}}' +
                 "</li></ul>",
    scope:{},
    controller:function($scope,cartItems){
        $scope.cartItems = cartItems.list();

    },
    link:function(){

    }}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Gaj2jOYIy1pxIPZwzWKS?p=preview)

I think this is a fine way to do it.  Since you need to access the same dataset from multiple directives, it makes sense to me to put the methods and data into a factory.

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <menu></menu>

    <br />Cart:<br />
    <cart></cart>
  </body>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('plunker',[])
.controller('MainCtrl', function() {

})
.factory('menuItems',function(){

    return {
        list:function(){
            var items = [{'name':'kabab'},
                 {'name':'chicken'},
                 {'name':'egg'},
                 {'name':'noodles'}];
            return items
        }
    };
})
.factory('cartItems',function(){
    return {

    orders: [],
    add: function(item) {
      this.orders.push(item)
    }
    }
    //return this.orders;
})
.directive('menu',function(cartItems){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        template:"<ul><li ng-repeat='item in menuItems'>"+
                  '{{item.name}}' +
                   "<button ng-click='addItem(item.name)'>Add</button></li></ul>",
        scope:{},
        controllerAs:'menuCtrl',
        controller:function($scope, menuItems){
            console.log("I am in menuDirective and outputting menuItems")
            console.log(menuItems);
            $scope.menuItems = menuItems.list();
            $scope.addItem = function(item) {
              cartItems.add(item);
              console.log(cartItems.orders)
            }
        },
        link:function(){

        }
    }
})
.directive('cart',function(){
    return{
    restrict:'E',
    template:"<ul><li ng-repeat='order in cartItems track by $index'>"+
                 '{{order}}' +
                 "</li></ul>",
    scope:{},
    controller:function($scope,cartItems){
        $scope.cartItems = cartItems.orders;

    },
    link:function(){

    }}
})
```

Any methods relating to the `orders` array should be put in the factory.  Your factory should encapsulate all logic related to that particular 'thing'.  Keeping the logic out of your directives gives you good abstraction, so if you need to change something, you know where all the logic is kept, rather than spread out in a bunch of directives.  So if you want to add an 'empty cart' method, or a 'delete from cart' method, I would put those into the factory, operate directly on the orders array, and return the updated array to whatever is calling the methods.

Comment: WHy did you include a `MainCtrl` controller here?

Comment: How are you able to access `add` method of `cartItems` factory from `menu` directive, without any kind of inheritance?

Comment: I just put the controller there...because you'll probably be using a controller at some point?

Comment: The cartItems factory is being injected into the menu directive.

Comment: oh ok my bad . . . i get it.

Comment: tpie: i might need more help from you as i try to implement a project for hotel client.